# Integration of Common platforms to SharePoint online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-list

Is it possible to integrate WhatsApp/facebook/ we chat/ Google forms to integrate with SharePoint online list? I am hoping input of SharePoint online list to be one of these for easy access to people who don't have direct access to SharePoint...

Comment: If WhatsApp/facebook/ we chat/ Google forms have exposed their APIs then everything is possible.

Comment: So, as of now we cant do anything about this?

Comment: Check on their websites if they have exposed any APIs or any documentation on their APIs. As far as I know, you will get facebook & google form APIs easily. Chatting apps are meant to be personal so you might not get them.

Comment: Ok. Let me check thanks.

Comment: check this for facebook - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/save-the-facebook-updates-to-sharepoint-list-using-microsoft-flow/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Some of the services already have APIs for direct integration but for the chat apps such as WhatsApp, you will need an intermediary service such as [Infobip](https://www.infobip.com/en/products/chat-apps) or [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following article, it list the currently supported connectors.

List of supported connectors:

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/?filter=&category=all